# Omit "git" from series of git commands

Tags: bash, git

When I am working with git, I often find myself typing a series of commands that all begin with 'git' followed by various arguments.

Is there anyway to enter a 'git-mode' that will let me use all of the git commands without the git prefix?

For example, instead of entering the following commands:

```
git fetch
git status 
git diff
git add file.txt
git commit 
git push
```

I would like to instead use:

```
enter-git-mode
fetch
status 
diff
add file.txt
commit 
push
exit-git-mode
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are willing to be in “git-mode” all the time,
the simple answer is to put the following commands:

```
alias fetch='git fetch'
alias status='git status'
alias diff='git diff'
alias add='git add'
alias commit='git commit'
alias push='git push'
```

into your `~/.bashrc`. 
But this may be undesirable,
if only because there is a regular command called `diff`,
and you wouldn’t be able to access it
if `diff` is aliased to `git diff`<sup>1</sup>. 
So the next, tiny, increase in complexity is to set it up
so that the aliases can be activated and deactivated dynamically. 
You can do that with

```
alias enter-git-mode="alias fetch='git fetch'; alias status='git status'; alias diff='git diff'; alias add='git add'; alias commit='git commit'; alias push='git push'"
alias exit-git-mode="unalias fetch status diff add commit push"
```

So now `enter-git-mode` is a command (alias)
that defines the first six aliases,
and `exit-git-mode` is a command that undefines them.

You can split that long command into multiple lines if you want:

```
alias enter-git-mode="alias fetch='git fetch';   alias status='git status';
                      alias diff='git diff';     alias add='git add';
                      alias commit='git commit'; alias push='git push'"
alias exit-git-mode="unalias fetch status diff add commit push"
```

This allows you to use these commands just like any other command; e.g.,

```
date; status; date              # A simple way of seeing how long a command takes.
time add .
commit &
commit && push
diff > differences.txt
```

and autocomplete,
and you can intermix regular Unix/Linux commands with `git` commands —
except, of course, you can’t run `diff`<sup>1</sup>.

Obviously, this does not magically handle *all* `git` commands. 
If you want to handle more subcommands (e.g., `archive` or `branch`),
you need to add them to the aliases.
________
<sup>1</sup> except by typing `/bin/diff` or `/usr/bin/diff`

Answer (score 2):

There are a few tools that do this. One of them is [`gitsh`](https://github.com/thoughtbot/gitsh), and their README.md page lists a few more.
This is providing quite a bit more than simply prepending `git` to your commands, but may still fit your needs.

Usage example from README.md:

```
sh$ gitsh
gitsh% status
gitsh% add .
gitsh% commit -m "Ship it!"
gitsh% push
gitsh% ctrl-d
sh$
```

Comment: This looks like a good solution.  But I notice from the documentation that, to run an ordinary Unix/Linux command (like `date` or `ls -al`) while you’re in `gitsh`, you must type a `!` first.  Depending on the user’s workflow, this might be cumbersome.

Answer (score 1):

A shell script named `git-mode` should do the trick:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -n "> "
while read line; do
    case $line in
        fetch*) git fetch
                ;;
        status*) git status
                 ;;
        # and so on
     esac

     echo -n "> "
done
```

In practice I would probably just alias `git` to `g` to remain flexible (or `git add` to `gadd`, `git fetch` to `gfetch` etc.).

Comment: I like this idea, but wonder if we could make it a little slicker. Couldn't we just use: while read line; do \ git $line \ echo -n "> " \ done

Comment: @PaulrBead How would you handle `git add foo.c` with that?

Comment: That works! :)
But using this approach sacrifices the use of autocomplete using the Tab key, which might be too inconvenient to use often.

Comment: This severely ties one arm behind the user’s back.   Using your script, the user can’t do things like `date; status`, `time add .`, `commit &`, `commit && push`, or `diff > differences.txt`.   Also, as written, your script will exit if the user types Ctrl+C.